# Flex div is growing vertically when hovered because of its content but not shrinking back

Tags: html, css, flexbox

Here is what I did, I extracted the important part: http://jsfiddle.net/P9Ftp/3/

My problem is that if the item contains too much text, it will wrap to the second line. If the space gets too small only if hovered though, it grows in order to show the text properly but does not shrink back down once the mouse leaves the field.

By increasing the left margin but not allowing for more space, the text wraps:

```
<div id="list">
    <section>
        <div class="pre"></div>
        <div class="content">asdf asdfadsf asdfa sdf adsfadsf asdf a</div>
        <div class="post"></div>
    </section>
</div>
```

The critical CSS part:

```
section:hover .content {
    margin-left: 32px;
}
```

Is this expected behaviour / what can I do to avoid this?

Thanks a lot in advance!

**UPDATE:** appears to be a Chrome issue. Workaround would be appreciated.

Comment: works for me on firefox. the problem shows up in chrome

Comment: That's what I'm using... Thanks for the information. A workaround for chrome would be appreciated then. I'll update

Comment: I'm noticing that if you resize the browser window, the "expanded" container shrinks to the correct size. I wonder if this is a bug

Comment: It seems to be working in chrome with this fiddle using the code you provided: http://jsfiddle.net/5RShp/. but that may be because of JSFiddle rather than chrome.

Comment: @LorenzoMarcon yes, that's what I've been thinking as well.

Comment: @advert2013 that's because I didn't provide everything you need to recreate the situation, there's more information in the fiddle.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A solution could be to add `display: block;` to `section` (or whatever other display style, such as `inline-block`)
This changes slightly the appearance, but maybe you can work on other rules to get the desired result.

In general, I think that adding `display: flex;` to all elements (`body *` rule) is too broad, and maybe could lead to undesired results.

Working fiddle on Chrome: http://jsfiddle.net/P9Ftp/4/

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, I think this is how I will solve it for now. I guess this is the right answer and will therefore be accepted since you answered the question fully ;)